# Individual Email Results stopped showing

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have configured the Individual Email Results on the Page Layout of a Contact. All results came through, however it suddenly stopped showing results the last month. I can't seem to find why this is happening. Did someone experienced this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes we have. There is an issue with your connector and you would need to refresh your SFMC token in Salesforce. If this doesnt work log a ticket with support.

Reference:

- [Clear Token](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214335&type=1)